# SharePoint 2016 Office online Server status is unhealthy

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, oos

I am trying to configure Office Online Server 2016( November release) on Windows Server 2012 R2 ( April 2014 update), which is brand new installation. 
Add all the required features using Powershell( restart the server at the end)
Installed All 4 Pre-req without any error
Restart the Server
Install the OOS 2016 without any issue
Run the Newoffice command to configure it on http ( completed successfully)
but when I get the machine status, health Status always Unhealthy.

In the Event Log Application, following Error reported

- event ID 1021 Source Perflib Windows cannot open the 32-bit
  extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_2.0.50727 in a 64-bit environment.
  Contact the file vendor to obtain a 64-bit version. Alternatively,
  you can open the 32-bit extensible counter DLL by using the 32-bit
  version of Performance Monitor. To use this tool, open the Windows
  folder, open the Syswow64 folder, and then start Perfmon.exe.
- Event ID 1017, Source PerfLib Disabled performance counter data
  collection from the "ASP.NET_2.0.50727" service because the
  performance counter library for that service has generated one or
  more errors. The errors that forced this action have been written to
  the application event log. Correct the errors before enabling the
  performance counters for this service.
- Event ID 1008 Source Perflin The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in
  DLL "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for
  this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of
  the Data section contains the error code. The Open Procedure for
  service "Lsa" in DLL "C:\Windows\System32\Secur32.dll" failed.
  Performance data for this service will not be available. The first
  four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.
- The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL
  "C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for
  this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of
  the Data section contains the error code.
- Event ID 2004, Source PerfLib Unable to open the Server service
  performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section
  contains the status code.

Event IDs from the Office Web App Logs

> Event ID 21077 Source Office Web Apps Monitors
>   WordDocumentSessionServiceWatchdog reported status for
>   WordDocumentSessionService in category 'Ping'. Reported status:
>   WordDocumentSessionService ping hit an exception Event ID 21072 Source
>   Office Web Apps Monitors Event ID 20173 Source Office Web Apps
>   Monitors Event ID 20005 Source Office Web Apps Monitors Event ID 21097
>   Source Office Web Apps Monitors Event ID 20876 Source Office Web Apps
>   Monitors Event ID 20857 Source Office Web Apps Monitors

I am totally clue less what should i do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days troubleshooting, Finally, I am able to nail it down.

Basically, There is one service called WMI performance Adapter which is stopped and set to manual start. As soon as I start that service and restart the WACM services then wait for 5 min. Now everything is working as expected.

- Go to Administrator Tools > Service > Scroll Down to **WMI
  Performance Adapter**
- If the Service stopped then start it...But if it running just restart it.
- Now Restart the Webapps service by running this command `Restart-Service WACSM`
- Now wait for 5 to 10 Mins and check the status of Office online server

Comment: I am using 2012R2 windows server as OWA server, i was able to view documents online perfectly . but automatically this feature is not working and i tried your solution to get server status healthy but still same error.